# scala: foldLeft with zipWithIndex

Tags: scala

The following code *works*:

```
likertRoundDfSeq:Seq[DataFrame] =    ......
likertRoundDfSeq match
  {

    case head :: tail => tail.foldLeft(head){(dforg,df1)=>
      DataFrameUtils.join(dforg,devianceFromAverageOneRound(df1),"A_RowId")
    }
  }
```

BUT, I need to add an index as an additional argument to `devianceFromAverageOneRound`

I thought of doing this with `zipWithIndex`
Perhaps, like this:

```
 likertRoundDfSeq match
  {

    case head :: tail => tail.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(head){(dforg,df1)=>
      DataFrameUtils.join(dforg,devianceFromAverageOneRound(df1,*myzipindex*),"A_RowId" )
    }
  }
```

But I am not sure how to break out the dataframe and idx in this case. Intellij does not seem to guide me on this, so I'm a bit lost

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: It should be something like `devianceFromAverageOneRound(df1._1, df1._2)`, same for the dforg value as well, but you'd probably have to call `foldLeft` with something like `(head, 0)`. Just an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tail of your DF Seq is now a list of Tuple2[DataFrame, Long], hence your `foldLeft` should look like the following:

```
case head :: tail => tail.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(head){ (dforg, df1) =>
  DataFrameUtils.join(dforg, devianceFromAverageOneRound(df1._1, df1._2), "A_RowId")
```

This assumes your new `devianceFromAverageOneRound(DataFrame, Long)` still returns a `DataFrame` (and not `Tuple2[DataFrame, Long]`).